# How to stop <ahref> voiding jquery model box?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I have a pop up box that is prompted from `<a>`. Inside of that I'm wanting to put content that has links via `<a>` inside. As soon as I put in another `<a href>` is breaks the whole box and all of the hidden content is exposed hence breaking my page.

```
<span class="modalboxContent">
    <div class="links_box">
        <div class="link_title_holder">
            <div class="link_title">
                <a href="/index.php/general/watch">
                    <span class="red">WATCH</span> Videos on topics you care about.
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="link_title">
                <a href="/index.php/general/read">
                    <span class="red">READ</span> Informational booklets and handouts.
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="link_title">
                <a href="/index.php/general/link">
                    <span class="red">LINK</span> Find additional online resources
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

thanks in advance and let me know if you need to see any other code.

Comment: need javascript code in order to find the problem

Comment: https://gist.github.com/37684343f204cab1c1f9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Changed the .on() handler to .live() handler to work with dynamicallt generated elements (Should Work Now)

[**.on() Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/wM4BG/3/)
[**.live() Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/wM4BG/4/)

**HTML** Style it with hover state and such

```
 <span id="clickme" class="simulatedlink" >Click Me!</span>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $('#clickme').live('click', function(){ window.location.href = 'http://www.videsignz.com/'; });
```

Comment: wonderful idea, however following your instructions exactly via your fiddle, there is no action via clicking simulated link. I'm using this as my latest jquery library<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hmmm...do you have a link to the page I can look at?

Comment: You need to put the Jquery .on() script in the body, below your html, otherwise the .on('click') will not bind to an element that doesnt yet exist.

Comment: Ok, check this out videsignz.com/testing/simulateclick.html I copied and pasted your code on my site...the only thing I can think of is the modalbox js may be interfering.  Can you give me the full link to the source for that so I can put it in my page and test? Also, is the modal box generated dynamically or is it already html on the page when it loads?

Comment: yes the box is generated dynamically. I'm on a dev so here is the link to the model.js  https://gist.github.com/2e2aa993daff3da8be25